# Systems programming qemu: unknown keycodes `(unnamed)'

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, qemu, systems-programming

I am trying to run qemu with code that my teacher provided so that we are able to work on our assignment. 
This is being run in Ubuntu 18.04

```
LIBPATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/

arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g ts.s -o ts.o

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g t.c -o t.o

arm-none-eabi-ld -T t.ld ts.o t.o -o t.elf

arm-none-eabi-ld -T t.ld -L $LIBPATH ts.o t.o -o t.elf -lgcc #-lstr

arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary t.elf t.bin

rm *.o *.elf

echo ready to go?
read dummy

qemu-system-arm -M realview-pbx-a9 -m 128M -kernel t.bin \
-serial mon:stdio -serial /dev/pts/2 -serial /dev/pts/2 -serial /dev/pts/2
```

And the numbers in the last line `-serial /dev/pts/#' are from running ps in the terminal and grabbing the number. All of this is in an executable file, and when I run the file the qemu screen does display, but when I press enter again I recieve this error message

```
unknown keycodes `(unnamed)', please report to qemu-devel@nongnu.org
```

I cannot seem to find any clear answer on how to solve this problem. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling qemu a couple of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QEMU's "unknown keycodes" message is about key handling in its graphics window, and means that the host keyboard mapping you're using has some odd setup that it doesn't entirely understand. Usually this means that a few keys won't work right  in the graphics window, and you can ignore it unless you're actually having a problem with them. The whole keycode system was completely rewritten in a newer version of QEMU, and this message doesn't even exist any more.

If your test program isn't expecting to use the graphical screen, then you can definitely ignore the message (indeed you could turn off the graphics screen entirely with -display none).

The command line options to QEMU you're using for the serial port look really odd -- you seem to be trying to connect multiple serial ports to the same host tty, which I'm pretty sure won't work right. Unless you're actually using serial ports 1 through 3, just drop those and use the serial port 0 that is set up with "-serial mon:stdio".